# Error building with webpack

Tags: node.js, windows, reactjs, webpack, build

I'm following a tutorial about React which includes the building process using webpack. Specifically, I'm trying to create two files (main and vendor). When I run build script (SET NODE_ENV=production && webpack --config webpack.config.babel.js) it crashes with the following error:

> <--- Last few GCs --->
>    
>      45011 ms: Scavenge 860.2 (895.2) -> 844.5 (895.2) MB, 0.2 / 0.0 ms [allocation failure].    45063 ms: Scavenge 860.2 (895.2) -> 844.5 (895.2) MB, 0.2 / 0.0 ms [allocation failure].    45115 ms: Scavenge 860.2 (895.2) -> 844.5 (895.2) MB, 0.2 / 0.0 ms [allocation failure].    45167 ms: Scavenge 860.2 (895.2) -> 844.5 (895.2) MB, 0.2 / 0.0 ms [allocation failure].    45219 ms: Scavenge 860.2 (895.2) -> 844.5 (895.2) MB, 0.2 / 0.0 ms [allocation failure].
>
> <--- JS stacktrace --->  
>   ==== JS stack trace =========================================   Security context: 000002E09573FA99 
>       2: takeMatchingModules [C:\Users\Cristi\Desktop\react_scafold\hello-world\node_modules\webpack-split-chunks\lib\Tools.js:~17] [pc=00000189
>   723E4510] (this=00000342038AF381 ,chunkList=00000342038502E9 ,testers=000001653754EB29 )
>       3: /* anonymous */ [C:\Users\Cristi\Desktop\react_scafold\hello-world\node_modules\webpack-split-ch...
>    
>   FATAL ERROR: invalid array length Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
>
> npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
>   npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
>   npm ERR! node v6.11.1 npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! hello-world@0.1.0 build: `SET NODE_ENV=production && webpack --config webpack.config.babel.js`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 3 npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Failed at the hello-world@0.1.0 build script 'SET NODE_ENV=production && webpack --config webpack.config.babel.js'.
>   npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
>   npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the hello-world package,
>
> npm ERR! not with npm itself.
>   npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
>   npm ERR!     SET NODE_ENV=production && webpack --config webpack.config.babel.js
>   npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
>   npm ERR!     npm bugs hello-world
>   npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
>   npm ERR!     npm owner ls hello-world
>   npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
>   npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Users\Cristi\Desktop\react_scafold\hello-world\npm-debug.log

---

**npm-debug.log file:**

> 0 info it worked if it ends with ok
>
> 1 verbose cli [ 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe',
>
> 1 verbose cli   'C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',
>
> 1 verbose cli   'run',
>
> 1 verbose cli   'build' ]
>
> 2 info using npm@3.10.10
>
> 3 info using node@v6.11.1
>
> 4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
>
> 5 info lifecycle hello-world@0.1.0~prebuild: hello-world@0.1.0
>
> 6 silly lifecycle hello-world@0.1.0~prebuild: no script for prebuild,
>   continuing
>
> 7 info lifecycle hello-world@0.1.0~build: hello-world@0.1.0
>
> 8 verbose lifecycle hello-world@0.1.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle
>   true
>
> 9 verbose lifecycle hello-world@0.1.0~build: PATH: C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Cristi\Desktop\react_scafold\hello-world\node_modules.bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA
>   Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Cristi\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\Cristi\AppData\Roaming\npm
>
> 10 verbose lifecycle hello-world@0.1.0~build: CWD:
>   C:\Users\Cristi\Desktop\react_scafold\hello-world
>
> 11 silly lifecycle hello-world@0.1.0~build: Args: [ '/d /s /c',
>
> 11 silly lifecycle   'SET NODE_ENV=production && webpack --config
>   webpack.config.babel.js' ]
>
> 12 silly lifecycle hello-world@0.1.0~build: Returned: code: 3  signal:
>   null
>
> 13 info lifecycle hello-world@0.1.0~build: Failed to exec build script
>
> 14 verbose stack Error: hello-world@0.1.0 build: `SET
>   NODE_ENV=production && webpack --config webpack.config.babel.js`
>
> 14 verbose stack Exit status 3
>
> 14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter. (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:255:16)
>
> 14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
>
> 14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
>
> 14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess. (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)
>
> 14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
>
> 14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
>
> 14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:891:16)
>
> 14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
>   (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
>
> 15 verbose pkgid hello-world@0.1.0
>
> 16 verbose cwd C:\Users\Cristi\Desktop\react_scafold\hello-world
>
> 17 error Windows_NT 6.3.9600
>
> 18 error argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
>
> 19 error node v6.11.1
>
> 20 error npm  v3.10.10
>
> 21 error code ELIFECYCLE
>
> 22 error hello-world@0.1.0 build: `SET NODE_ENV=production && webpack
>   --config webpack.config.babel.js`
>
> 22 error Exit status 3
>
> 23 error Failed at the hello-world@0.1.0 build script 'SET
>   NODE_ENV=production && webpack --config webpack.config.babel.js'.
>
> 23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm
>   installed.
>
> 23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the hello-world
>   package,
>
> 23 error not with npm itself.
>
> 23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
>
> 23 error     SET NODE_ENV=production && webpack --config
>   webpack.config.babel.js
>
> 23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this
>   project with:
>
> 23 error     npm bugs hello-world
>
> 23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
>
> 23 error     npm owner ls hello-world
>
> 23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> 24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

---

**package.json:**

```
{

  "name": "hello-world",

  "version": "0.1.0",

  "private": true,

  "dependencies": {

    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",

    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",

    "express": "^4.15.3",

    "path": "^0.12.7",

    "prop-types": "^15.5.8",

    "react": "^15.6.1",

    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",

    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",

    "react-scripts": "1.0.10",

    "serve": "^6.0.3"

  },

  "devDependencies": {

    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",

    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",

    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",

    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",

    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",

    "babel-preset-react-hmre": "^1.1.1",

    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",

    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",

    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",

    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",

    "open": "^0.0.5",

    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",

    "url-loader": "^0.5.9",

    "webpack": "^3.5.5",

    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.12.0",

    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.19.0",

    "webpack-split-chunks": "^0.2.1"

  },

  "scripts": {

    "start": "babel-node --max-old-space-size=1024 src/server",

    "production": "SET NODE_ENV=production BABEL_ENV=production && npm run 
build && npm start",
    "build": "SET NODE_ENV=production && webpack --config 
webpack.config.babel.js"
  }

}
```

---

**webpack.config.babel.js**

```
// Dependencies
import webpack from 'webpack';
import path from 'path';
import ChunksPlugin from 'webpack-split-chunks';

// Environment
const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

// Paths
const PATHS = {
  index: path.join(__dirname, 'src/index'),
  build: path.join(__dirname, 'src/public'),
  src: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
};

const getDevtool = () => 'cheap-module-eval-source-map';
const getEntry = () => {
  const entry = [PATHS.index];

  if (isDevelopment) {
    entry.push('webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true');
  }

  return entry;
};
const getOutput = () => ({
  path: PATHS.build,
  publicPath: '/',
  filename: '[name].bundle.js'

});
const getPlugins = () => {
  const plugins = [
    new ChunksPlugin({
      to: 'vendor',
      test: /node_modules/
    })
  ];

  if (isDevelopment) {
    plugins.push(
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
      new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin()
    );
  } else {
    plugins.push(
      new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        compress: {
          //screw_ie8: true,
          warnings: false
        }
      })
    );
  }

  return plugins;
};
const getLoaders = () => ({
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.js?$/,
      include: PATHS.src,
      loader: 'babel-loader'
    },
    {
      test: /(\.css)$/,
      loader: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
    },
    {
      test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
      loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'
    }
  ]

}  );

export default {
  devtool: getDevtool(),
  entry: getEntry(),
  output: getOutput(),
  plugins: getPlugins(),
  module: getLoaders()
};
```

Answer (score 0):

First try to build using Parallel Webpack - 
-> node ./node_modules/parallel-webpack/bin/run.js --config webpack.config.babel.js

If the error don't resolve try increasing memory allocation to Node 
-> node --max-old-space-size=1024 ./node_modules/parallel-webpack/bin/run.js --config webpack.config.babel.js

https://medium.com/@vuongtran/how-to-solve-process-out-of-memory-in-node-js-5f0de8f8464c